# Why do I need a Application_Model_User and Application_Model_DbTable_User in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there any point in having both? I followed a Zend tutorial which told me to create a user model but can't I just model the user in the DB model class?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part and parcel of the concept of "separation of concerns" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Your model class takes care of business logic, validation, variable manipulation etc and your db model class should just handle dealing with the database, that way if you need to replace the db model it wont affect the main model as much, and if you replace the main model it wont affect the db model as long as the right parameters are passed into it.

Comment: What Gabriel said.  For example, you can see how that separation can be taken advantage of clearly in the Data Mapper pattern.  http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html

Comment: @ficuscr, actually he probably can't, not yet. I read that myself over and over but It took experience to make me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can model your user in Application_Model_DbTable_User (DbTable class) and it will work fine as long as all of the data you need is in that one table.

At some point you will likely start working with objects that should be represented in more then one table. This is when you will discover the need for a different way to do things.

A better simple example of where a mapper and domain object might matter:

***The mp3 file.***
 At it simplest a single music file should probably be represented by at least 3 db tables:

1. **album**: a table representing the album the song comes from
2. **artist**: the artist that recorded the song
3. **track**: the information about the track itself

each ***artist*** can have multiple ***albums***, each ***album*** will have one ***artist*** and will have multiple ***tracks***, each ***track*** will belong to one ***album*** and one ***artist*** (different versions will be different tracks).

As you can see the database stucture of even a simple mp3 collection can become very complex very quickly. In most cases even a simple user record will spread across multiple tables depending upon how much and what kind of data is being persisted.

For some help in understanding how and why to implement mappers and models I found these resources very helpful.

[Building a Domain Model](http://phpmaster.com/building-a-domain-model/), covers what a domain model is and how to build one in PHP.
[Adding Mappers to a Domain Model](http://phpmaster.com/integrating-the-data-mappers/), adds mapper function to the same domain model.
[Survive the Deepend](http://survivethedeepend.com/), A Zend Framework starter that focuses on models and testing.

The first two links are done in plain PHP but are still very helpful.